# In Unity, the character's spine position reference changed after I put something into its hand

Tags: unity

The situation can be illustrated by a few pictures.

here is a character[image]

After i put a gun under his right hand[image]

As you can see, when I select spine.003, its position is now located at the gun. When I try to rotate the spine, it will use that gun position as a pivot point, which is definitely unintended. And after I delete the gun, the spine's position goes back, and everything is fine again.[image]

Strangely enough, the breast position remains unaffected, while only the spine is affected. Why is this happening?

Comment: Are you using any [inverse kinematics](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/InverseKinematics.html)?

Comment: I'm not using any IK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Scene view, click the "Toggle Tool Handle Position" dropdown, and select "Pivot".

[image]

Comment: Thankyou so much!

Comment: @pond You're welcome, glad to help!